# OpenERP Apps for more than 3 users

Tags: module, odoo, openerp-7

one month before i installed openerp 7 all in one version in windows, i have successfully installed the apps when i have user less then 3 but when i create more users and try to install more app openerp account ask for email and password after that he display following message (An OpenERP Enterprise subscription is required for one-click installation of OpenERP Apps for more than 3 users.)
how to fix this issue please guide me,

i also delete all the user except administrator but same message is displayed. even i deleted the database and restore another database and try to install app but same message is displayed with old database name and same number of users

Answer (score 0):

You just need to sign in with the account you used to download the installation package. The local server will then start downloading the files.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the APPS section of your account to get the download.

Ideally though, you can also set up BZR to do a pull so when there are updates you can get them in relatively easily also.

Answer (score 0):

Well clearly it is a bug in OpenERP v7.

I have created a bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-addons/+bug/1260377 fell free to subscribe to it.